# Can we live without constructors?

Tags: object-oriented-design, class-design

Let's say in some reason all objects are created this way $obj = CLASS::getInstance(). Then we inject dependencies using setters and perform starting initialization using $obj->initInstance(); Are there any real troubles or situations, which can't be solved, if we won't use constructors at all?

P.s. the reason to create object this way, is that we can replace class inside getInstance() according to some rules.

I'm working in PHP, if that matter

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: PHP (why does it matter?)

Comment: Looks like that what you want to do can be achieved using the Factory pattern.

Comment: Just as a note: the factory patern @superM mentioned is one way to implement Inversion of Control (Dependency Injection) is another one.

Comment: Isn't that roughly what javascript does with objects?

Comment: ...or Perl, for that matter. Technically, Perl doesn't have constructors in the strict sense: actual object creation is done using [`bless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html), which marks a primitive type (typically a hash) as belonging to a class, and while it's common for a class to include a factory method named `new` that sets up and blesses a new instance, that's just a convention.

Comment: Your apporoach does not rule away constructors per se, you just technically move the initialization to dependency injection and the init method.

Comment: IoC frameworks allow you to inject dependencies into constructors. This is normally done from the composition root of the application and this is the only place that is aware of IoC container (framework).

Answer (score 44):

I'd say that this severly hinders your design space.

Constructors are a great place to initialize and validate parameters passed in. If you can no longer use them for that, then initialization, state handling (or plain out denying constructor of "broken" objects) becomes a lot harder and partially impossible.

For example, if every `Foo` object needs a `Frobnicator` then it might check in its constructor if the `Frobnicator` is non-null. If you take away the constructor, then it gets harder to check. Do you check at every point where it would be used? In an `init()` method (effectively externalizing the constructor method)? Never check it and hope for the best?

While you *could* probably still implement everything (after all, you're still turing complete), some things will be a lot harder to do.

Personally I'd suggest looking into [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)/[Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). These techniques also allow switching concrete implementation classes, but they don't prevent writing/using constructors.

Comment: What did you mean by "or plain out denying constructor of "broken" objects"?

Comment: @Geek: a constructor can inspect its argument and decide if those would result in a working object (for example if your object needs a `HttpClient` then it checks if that parameter is non-null). And if those constraints are not met, then it can throw an exception. That's not really possible with the construct-and-set-values approach.

Comment: I think OP was just describing externalization of the constructor inside `init()`, which is entirely possible—although this just imposes more of a maintenance burden.

Answer (score 26):

2 advantages to constructors:

### Constructors allow for the an object's construction steps to be done atomically.

I could avoid a constructor and use setters for everything, but what about mandatory properties as Joachim Sauer suggested?  With a constructor, an object owns its own construction logic so as to ensure that there **are no invalid instances of such class**.

If creating an instance of `Foo` requires 3 properties to be set, the constructor could take a reference to all 3, validate them and throw an exception if they are invalid.

### Encapsulation

By relying solely on setters, the burden is on the consumer of an object to build it properly.  There could be different combinations of properties that are valid.

For example, every `Foo` instance needs either an instance of `Bar` as property `bar` or an instance of `BarFinder` as property `barFinder`.  It can use either one.  You can create a constructor for every valid set of parameters and enforce the conventions that way.

The logic and semantics for the objects live within the object itself.  It's good encapsulation.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can live without constructors.

Sure, you may end up with a lot of duplicated boiler plate code.  And if your application is of any scale, you'll likely spend a lot of time trying to locate the source of a problem when that boilerplate code isnt used consistently across the application.

But no, you don't strictly 'need' your own constructors.  Of course, you don't strictly 'need' classes and objects, either.

Now if your goal is to use some sort of factory pattern for object creation, that isnt mutually exclusive to using constructors when initializing your objects.

Comment: Absolutely. One can even live without classes and objects, to begin with.

Comment: All hail the mighty assembler!

Answer (score 9):

The advantage of using constructors is that they make it easier to ensure that you will never have an invalid object.

A constructor gives you the opportunity to set all member variables of the object to a valid state. When you then ensure that no mutator method can change the object to an invalid state, you will never have an invalid object, which will save you from a lot of bugs.

But when a new object is created in an invalid state and you must call some setters to put it into a valid state in which it can be used, you are risking that a consumer of the class forgets to call these setters or calls them incorrectly and you end up with an invalid object.

A workaround could be to create objects only through a factory-method which checks every object it creates for validity before returning it to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

> $obj = CLASS::getInstance(). Then we inject dependencies using setters and perform starting initialization using $obj->initInstance();

I think you're making this more difficult than it needs to be.  We can inject dependencies just fine through the constructor - and if you have a lot of them, just use a dictionary-like structure so you can specify what ones you want to use:

```
$obj = new CLASS(array(
    'Frobnicator' => (),
    'Foonicator' => (),
));
```

And within the constructor, you can ensure consistency like so:

```
if (!array_key_exists('Frobnicator', $args)) {
    throw new Exception('Frobnicator required');
}
if (!array_key_exists('Foonicator', $args)) {
    $args['Foonicator'] = new DefaultFoonicator();
}
```

`$args` can then be used to set private members as necessary.

When done entirely within the constructor like so, there will never be an intermediate state where `$obj` exists but is not initialized, as there would be in the system described in the question.  It's better to avoid such intermediate states, because you can't guarantee the object is always going to be used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually thinking about similar things.

The question I asked was "What constructor does, and is it possible to do it differently?" I reached those conclusions:

- It ensures some properties are initialized. By accepting them as parameters and setting them. But this could easily be enforced by compiler. By simply annotating the fields or properties as "required" the compiler would check during creation of the instance if everything is properly set. The call to create the instance would probably be same, there just wouldn't be any constructor method.
- Ensures the properties are valid. This could be easily achieved by assert condition. Again you would just annotate the properties with correct conditions. Some languages already do this.
- Some more complex construction logic. Modern patterns don't recommend to do that in constructor, but propose using specialized factory methods or classes. So the use of constructors in this case is minimal.

So to answer your question: Yes, I believe it is possible. But it would require some big changes in language design.

And I just noticed my answer is pretty OT.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do nearly everything without using constructors but this is clearly squandering benefits of Object-Oriented Programming languages.

In modern languages (I'll talk here about C# which I program in) you can limit parts of code that can be run **only** in a constructor. Thanks to which you can avoid clumsy mistakes. One of such a thing is **readonly** modifier:

```
public class A {
    readonly string rostring;

    public A(string arg) {
        rostring = arg;
    }

    public static A CreateInstance(string arg) {
        var result = new A();
        A.rostring = arg;  // < because of this the code won't compile!
        return result;
    }
}
```

As [recommended by Joachim Sauer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/224034/31260) previously instead of using `Factory` design patter read about `Dependency Injection`. I would recommend reading [Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann](http://www.manning.com/seemann/).

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate an object with a type depending on the requirements it is absolutely possible. It could be the object itself, using global variables of the system to return a specific type.

However, have a class in the code that can be "All" is *the concept of dynamic type*. I personally believe this approach create inconsistency in your code, make the test complexes*, and "the future becomes uncertain" with respect to the flow of the proposed work.

**I am referring to the fact that the tests must consider first the type, second the result you want to achieve. Then you are creating large nested test.*

Answer (score 1):

To balance some of the other answers, claiming:

> A constructor gives you the opportunity to set all member variables of
>   the object to a valid state... you will never have an invalid object, which will save you from a lot of bugs.

and

> With a constructor, an object owns its own construction logic so as to ensure that there are no invalid instances of such class.

Such statements sometimes imply the assumption that:

> If an class has a constructor that, by the time it exits, has put the object into a valid state, and none of the class's methods mutate that state to make it invalid, then it is impossible for code outside the class to detect an object of that class in an invalid state.

But this is not quite true. Most languages do not have a rule against a constructor passing `this` (or `self` or whatever the language calls it) to external code. Such a constructor completely abides by the rule stated above, and yet it risks exposing semi-constructed objects to external code. It's a minor point but easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat anecdotal, but I usually reserve constructors for state essential for the object to be complete and usable.  Barring any setter-injection, once the constructor is run, my object should be able to perform the tasks required of it.

Anything that can be deferred, I leave out of the constructor (preparing output values, etc).  With this approach, I feel not using constructors for anything but dependency injection makes sense.

This also has the added benefit of hard-wiring your mental design process to not do anything prematurely.  You won't initialize or perform logic that may never end up being used because at best all you're doing is basic setup for the work ahead.